# AngularJS how to force an input to be re-rendered on blur

Tags: angularjs

I have some custom validation code, which includes a $formatter.  (I store currency in pence for correctness, but display in pounds.pence.)

If the user types '10' into the input (which is a valid value), the input remains displaying '10' after they move to the next field.

I would like it to display 10.00 for consistency.

If the model changed the value to 1000, then the formatter would make the field display '10.00'.

I would like the formatter to run on field.blur() (so long as the input is valid).

My problem is that if I change the model value from 10 to 10, there is understandably no change, and so the field is not re-rendered.

code:

```
var CURRENCY_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+(\.?\d?\d?)?$/;
app.directive('currency', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        if (CURRENCY_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          ctrl.$setValidity('currency', true);
          console.log("valid");
          return viewValue * 100;
        } else if (viewValue === '') {
          return 0;
        } else {
          // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
          ctrl.$setValidity('currency', false);
          console.log("invalid");
          return undefined;
        }
      });
      ctrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
         if (modelValue === 0) { // we're using integer pence, so this is safe
             return '';
         }
         return (modelValue / 100).toFixed(2); 
      });
    }
  };
});
```

P.S. This has nothing to do with Angular's built-in 'currency'.

---

Update: I've added a 'renderOnBlur' directive, as per Andy's answer.  It gets called, but calling the render method does not re-render the input.  i.e. '10' stays as '10', rather than changing to '10.00' as desired.

(When the model value changes in these fields, they are correctly rendered with the 2 decimal places.)

The page which Andy mentions http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController says that you have to implement `$render` yourself.  This seems odd, as the inputs are already rendered correctly when the model value changes.

```
app.directive('renderOnBlur', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                console.log('rendering ctrl', ctrl);
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }
    };  
});
```

P.S. I have no idea what `restrict: 'A',` does - it's true cargo-cult programming at its worst.  The `require: 'ngModel',` seems necessary to populate the `ctrl` parameter.

---

Inspired by the answer from @Dan Doyen, I rewrote it as:

```
app.directive('renderOnBlur', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                var viewValue = ctrl.$modelValue;
                for (var i in ctrl.$formatters) {
                    viewValue = ctrl.$formatters[i](viewValue);
                }
                ctrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }
    };  
});
```

This has the benefit of being generic for any $formatter, rather than repeating the formatter code as in Dan's answer.

Comment: 10.00 === 10 //true; .00 don't means anything on javascript

Comment: @ShadowBelmolve please see the comment under your answer.  Do you have any experience of AngularJS?

Comment: restrict: 'A' means you only want to allow the directive to be used like an attribute <input render-on-blur>, there are 4 different types of restrictions the others are 'E'lement <render-on-blur>, 'C'lass <input class='render-on-blur'> and Co'M'ment (which is less used - see doc). You can have multiple restrict: 'EAC'

Comment: @chrisdew this is a useful thread, making a jsfiddle of the entire directives used in the question will help others to quickly play around and learn more. Most of them come here while browsing the web and looking for some kind of ng understanding.

Comment: Do you have an example of a (karma?) test of your directive?

Comment: (Sorry, just learning Angular...) So your view should be something like `<input currency render-on-blur>`, right? I.e.: both "currency" and "render-on-blur" attributes should be specified?

Comment: About `$formatters`, the Angular documentation says "The functions are called in reverse array order, each passing the value through to the next." The directive calls them in the wrong order. Just thought I'd note this for anyone else, as this bit me when working with multiple formatters.

Comment: Your solution should be posted as an answer too. I just used it to fix a similar issue so thank you! You should also precise that it's based on [angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/056a31700803c0a6014b43cfcc36c5c500cc596e/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L822)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your controller's $modelValue is being updated properly, however,  but since the blur event is happening outside of angular, it seems your $viewValue is not. How about this?

```
 elm.bind('blur', function() {
       ctrl.$viewValue = (ctrl.$modelValue / 100).toFixed(2);
       ctrl.$render();
 });
```

Comment: Your answer inspired a better solution.  Please see the end of my question for a generic solution.

Comment: @chrisdew I'm glad I inspired you to get to a generic solution. I was (obviously) focusing on your particular apps' issue. I'm going to play with it. This might be an interesting technique to use in the angular-ui group. I'm going to run it by my fellow collaborators.

Answer (score 3):

A little improved:
Do not reformat if the value is not valid (in my case invalid text just got cleared on blur, which is bad for usability, I think).

Also, like Dark Falcon said: Formatters should be iterated backwards.

Finally do not iterate over arrays with for-in, at least not without checking hasOwnProperty() (for me the code crashed because it treated Array.find() as a formatter).

```
// Reformat text on blur
elements.bind('blur', function() {
    if(!ngModel.$valid) {
        return;
    }
    var viewValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
    var formatters = ngModel.$formatters;
    for (var i = formatters.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        viewValue = formatters[i](viewValue);
    }
    ngModel.$viewValue = viewValue;
    ngModel.$render();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative implementation is to trigger angular's formatters. Angular 1.5 implementation watches $modelValue for changes, and then triggers $formatters. To do this manually, one can do this

```
function triggerFormattersAndRender(ngModel, scope) {
  /* Triggers angulars formatters, which watches for $modelValue changes */
  var originalModelValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
  if (originalModelValue === null) return;

  ngModel.$modelValue = null;
  scope.$digest();
  ngModel.$modelValue = originalModelValue;
  scope.$digest();
}
```

And then in the directive

```
function link(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

    elem.bind('blur', function() {
        triggerFormattersAndRender(ngModel, scope);
    });

    // when we get focus, display full precision
    elem.bind('focus', function() {
      if (ngModel.$modelValue) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$modelValue.toString());
        ngModel.$render();
      }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ctrl.$render on blur.

`elm.bind('blur', function() { ctrl.$render() });`

See it in [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController).

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing this, but $render does nothing.  I've updated the question with a new section.

Answer (score -1):

`10.00 === 10` true

`a=10.00`

`console.log(a)` 10

.00 don't means anything on javascript, because of this your 10.00 are becoming 10

I suggest to make the value a String so you can create the format that you want

Comment: This isn't a question about Javascript per se, it's about AngularJS.  Have you read/understood the code?  The model values are stored as integer numbers of pence (cents), but the form input element deals with strings which contain a rendering of the value, in pounds (dollars) with two decimal places.  `(modelValue / 100).toFixed(2)` creates a string from an integer.