# Angular $scope not updating when passing value through parser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Notice that even values which pass validation are not making it intact through the parser. The parser returns the correct value, but then when the formatter is called the old value is still present in the model. Can someone explain this to me?

Here's the plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/uSLkKtLZIU63wRou3x8V?p=preview

and the code

```
angular.module('timeEntryModule', []).directive('timeEntryTotalHoursInput', function() {
return {
    require: '^ngModel',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
            if (modelValue === 0) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return modelValue.toFixed(2);
            }
        });

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            var tempVal = parseFloat(viewValue);
            if (tempVal) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('timeEntryInputError', true);
                ngModel.$modelValue = tempVal;
            } else {
                ngModel.$setValidity('timeEntryInputError', false);
                ngModel.$modelValue = undefined;               
            }

            return ngModel.$modelValue;            
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
angular.module('timeEntryModule').controller('TimeEntryCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.testproperty = 2;

}]);

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="timeEntryModule">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TimeEntryCtrl">
    <input ng-model="testproperty" time-entry-total-hours-input />
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: I would expect that when I enter a new value, say 3, that it would pass through the parser, be returned  by the parser since it does pass the validation logic, from there the updated value should reflect in the $scope.testproperty. Then angular should see the change in $scope.testproperty and enter into the formatter, where it should be formatted to 2 decimal places and ultimately the new formatted value should show in the view.

Comment: Please add content from your link directly into the question -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played with your plnkr and I think you would be better served to respond to blur event, here's what I quickly came up with
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/icRfuqfuIEGUw5d3hOWp?p=preview)

I think you are in more control of things in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I do see that this works somewhat, but it doesn't answer what was wrong with my original solution. Your solution seems to be allowing bad values to hit the model, and then on the blur event goes back and patches them up, which from my understanding of angular model binding bad values should never make it to the model.

Comment: It also seems to be updating the UI manually as opposed to updating the property on the model and allowing two way binding to do the work. I can't seem to get it to catch invalid values like letters and symbols.  All in all I may attempt to retrofit your solution to work but I would much prefer to get some clarity on how to properly use the formatters and parsers. Thanks you for the answer though I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Josh, I think two way binding was getting your way, i put console statements in your original one and it revealed a bit of race happening. I haven't spent a lot of time with formatters and parsers so i may have taken a simplified approach and it may be a better one, it actually motivates me to explore it more.

Comment: Well again I thank you for your effort! I will use this to get rolling again, but yeah it would be awesome if you could look into formatters and parsers as those would allow bad values to be caught before they get to the model, and also enables true validation before the blur event so that bad key presses don't even register in the input box.

Comment: And actually since the bad values are making it to the model this solution is not workable for me, since there are other elements in the UI that are performing functions on these values which cause errors during the time between the bad value being entered and the blur event firing.

Comment: From reading the API Reference on NgModelController. It says "It purposefully does not contain any logic which deals with DOM rendering or listening to DOM events." I don't think $parsers or $formatters therefore take any notice of changes made to the input box. And so you need to add a directive which watches for changes to the input and acts accordingly, blocking unwanted input.

Comment: Don, I actually found an old post of yours that kind of made things clear. I should have known that updating the model value from the parser will not update the UI automatically. I was able to add a keyup event to the directive that forces the reupdate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380866/angularjs-how-to-force-an-input-to-be-re-rendered-on-blur

Comment: Josh, keyup may be problematic since every key stroke will cause your ui to be updated, this is why i went with blur. I might suggest you take a look at either angular-ui or angular bootstrap projects for ideas. Also, you might want to think of a different approach and that is to use input[number] and use angular's built in number filter. You could still create a directive that uses the number filter (I've done this before with currency filter). Just some ideas...