# Format issue with angular directive

Tags: angularjs

Trying to learn AngularJS (v 1.x) and having some issues with how to best approach a scenario I have.

I want to be able to display an html input control to the user that allows them to enter a % for interest rates.   In the database, I want to store the value as a decimal with no formatting (eg.  0.25 for 25%), but in the UI I want to be able to display the 25%.   If the user enters a value into the input, I want them to be able to enter it as 25 (without the %) and have the data sent to database as .25 (ie...no backend validation to "format", just validate the value is in acceptable range 0-1).  Based on all the examples I have seen online so far, a custom directive is the best way to approach this.  I built a simple directive that is working to accomplish most of my requirement, but it won't display the % if the user hand enters a value and leaves the field.   It just stays as 25.   I created a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmdxv10c/) that shows this behavior.

What I am trying to figure out is how to use the directive I have built to handle formatting of the data whether it is put into the model via code or manually by the user.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for completeness:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input my-directive name="test" ng-model="item" placeholder="Type in a percentage as a whole #..." style="display:block;width:100%;">
    <button type="button" ng-click="item = .25">Set model to "25%"</button></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <span ng-bind="item"></span>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function($scope){
$scope.item = '.49';

$scope.$watch('item', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if (newVal !== oldVal){
        console.log(newVal);
    }
});
});

angular.module("app").directive("myDirective", function(){
   return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        controller.$parsers.push(function (data) {
            //convert data from view format to model format

            if (data) {
                return data / 100;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });

        controller.$formatters.push(function (data) {
            //convert data from model format to view format
            if (data) {
                return (data * 100).toFixed(3).toString() + "%";
            }
            else
            {
                return "0.000%";
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Looks like a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380866/angularjs-how-to-force-an-input-to-be-re-rendered-on-blur ; seems like the accepted answer (or final result in the original question) should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks mrusinak....worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app.js**

```
loanProposalApp.directive('renderOnBlur', renderOnBlur);
```

**renderOnBlur.js**

```
var renderOnBlur = ['CONFIG', function (CONFIG) {
    var controllerFunc = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }];
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.bind('blur', function () {
                var viewValue = ctrl.$modelValue;
                for (var i in ctrl.$formatters) {
                    viewValue = ctrl.$formatters[i](viewValue);
                }
                ctrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }
    };
}];
```